Free monads without fixing the base category
Usually, free monads are defined with respect to a fixed base category.
By this I mean that given an endofunctor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$, the free monad $\bar{F}$ on $F$ is defined using only monads on $\mathcal{C}$ and monad morphisms over $\text{id}_\mathcal{C}$. There are two ways, which are equivalent on nice categories according to the nlab:

$\bar{F}$ is free w.r.t. the forgetful functor from monads on $\mathcal{C}$ to endofunctors on $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. for any monad $T$ on $\mathcal{C}$, monad morphisms $\bar{F} \to T$ over $\text{id}_\mathcal{C}$ are in bijection to morphisms of endofunctors $F \to T$ over $\text{id}_\mathcal{C}$.
There is an equivalence $F\text{-Alg}_\mathbf{End} \simeq \bar{F}\text{-Alg}_\mathbf{Mon}$ of categories over $\mathcal{C}$. According to the nlab such an equivalence is automatically an isomorphism.

But more generally we have the forgetful (2-)functor from monads to endofunctors on arbitrary categories!
Do (some) free objects w.r.t. this functor exist?
Are they connected to the usual free monads?
I don't see why a free monad in the usual sense should be free in the non-fixed base category sense.
The other direction sounds more plausible, but I don't see it either, since $\mathbf{Mon}$ has morphisms over other endofunctors than the identity, but $\mathbf{Mon}_\mathcal{C}$ doesn't.
Does it matter if we're talking about the strictly or weakly free objects?
Can we show, similarly to the situation with algebras mentioned above, that a weakly free object is strictly free?
This would explain why we can ignore the 2-categorical structure, like we do in the usual setting.
After all, a monad morphism over an identity functor can have nontrivial endo-2-morphisms.
Or do we usually ignore them because they are in particular endo-transformations on identity functors, and lots of categories that we usually consider examples of monads on have centers that range from boring to trivial?

Can you give a definition (or reference) for the 2-category $\mathbf{Mon}$ and its forgetful functor to endofunctors on arbitrary categories?

@AlexKruckman see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92093/functors-between-monads-what-are-these-really-called

@KevinCarlson thx for providing the reference. Street's paper cited there is where I read about it first.

As far as the question itself, I have no idea, really, but the first thing I'd try to do is see whether I can fit this into Kelly's formalism in the big paper on transfinite constructions.

I've always found that paper too daunting. Is there a more readable source for this material by now?
